# What are the dangers when using "!=" "not equal" in the stop condition

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

```
count = 10;  //may queried from DB 

while(0 != count) {
    --count;
    //do_lottery();
}
```

I heard a story that a company using this piece of code unexpectedly gave out a lot of iPads as gifts.
Because the counter goes below 0 and the code still running without an end.

How could it happen? any scenario?

about multi-threads and lock?

Comment: **T1: count=1 => 0 != count**;

T2: count=1 => 0 != count ;

**T1: --count; => count=0**;

T2: --count; => count=-1;

Comment: Check https://deadlockempire.github.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, with threads, it's possible.

Let's say you have two threads running exactly the same code and `count` is set to one.

Thread 1 checks the condition and enters the loop but, before it can decrement `count`, it's swapped out for thread 2.

Thread 2 enters the loop (because `count` is still one) and decrements `count` before being swapped out. The `count` is now zero.

Thread 1 then runs again and the code it executes is to decrement `count` (to negative one). At that point, it will be quite a while before `count` reaches zero again, assuming it wraps at all. In the meantime, both threads will continue to run.

However, this is not so much a problem of using the "wrong" comparison operator as it is not protecting resources from concurrent access by multiple threads. In other words, similar code (using `!=` along with a mutual exclusion semaphore) will work fine:

```
count = 10;
init_mutex(count_lock);

lock_mutex(count_lock);
while (0 != count) {
    --count;
    unlock_mutex(count_lock);
    do_lottery();
    lock_mutex(count_lock);
}
unlock_mutex(count_lock);
```